# safari 100% width for Button doesn't work

Tags: css, safari, width

Hi and thank you for Helping in advacend.
I have an HTML 5 app that runs on IOS and my buttons 
align in a div on the right correctly but on the right there is like a 10px space 
even thoe i have no padding or margin.

```
  .FormElement .typeButton
     {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background-color:#f7f7f7;
      font-size: 14pt;
      border:none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #007aff;
      height: 35px;

  }
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, this is almost impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: sry I didn't noticed the missing code

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with your surrounding styles which are not listed here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works for apps but this problem seems familiar...
If i'm right you should add the following:

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
}
```

I think that might help...

Comment: Is it possible to give us a fiddle?